# Regex returning wrong string/variable?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to secure a HLS stream using the secure_link module in nginx. I'm doing this in two parts:

First the URL is a "SEO" friendly version, this gets rewritten to the secure_link URL which has the ?token=xxx&?expires=000.

This gets processed in the next block, and here I ONLY want to test a part of the URL (stream name in this case) and not the whole URI. I'm using a regex to get the part of the URL I need to test in a variable. But for some reason every time I execute a request I get the wrong variable here (as outputted in the debug return line) if I use the "SEO" friendly URL that is rewritten, I get the $1 from *the original* url, and not the $1 of the "new* (re-written) URL.

If I submit the manually rewritten request I get the correct output for that variable. So this is only happening when I'm using the first rewritten URL.

Can someone point me as to what I going on here and how I can fix this? I'm out of ideas.

Demo URL:
`https://myserver.com/live/hls/PSBOBrr5bVsd3wPLMMQE7Q/1658978846/AdminTest_1080/index.m3u8`

Nginx config:

```
        location /live {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length' always;
            rewrite  /hls/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/(.*)\.(ts|key|m3u8)$ /hls/$3/$4.$5?token=$1&expires=$2;
            root /mnt/not-exist;
        }

        location ~ "/hls/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/" {
#       location ~ /hls/(?<alias>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/ { #TRIED BOTH REGEX HERE, BOTH SAME RESULT
            #internal;

            secure_link $arg_token,$arg_expires;
            secure_link_md5 "$host $1 $secure_link_expires $remote_addr secret";
#            if ($secure_link = "")  { return 403; }
#           if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }

    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "secure_link: $host $1 $secure_link_expires $remote_addr "; # FOR DEBUGGING
        }
```

When submitting the above example to the first location block I get the following output:

```
secure_link: myserver.com PSBOBrr5bVsd3wPLMMQE7Q  127.0.0.1
```

Which is clearly incorrectly returning another part of the URL ($1 from the first location block, not the current location block)

When using a manually crafted URL:

```
https://myserver.com/hls/AdminTest_1080/index.m3u8?token=token&expires=0000
```

I get the following (correct output):

```
secure_link: myserver.com AdminTest_1080  127.0.0.1
```

At this point I'm even considering that this might be a bug? Hoping for valuable input from the community!

Comment: Your `location /live` block is never used as the regex `/hls/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/` matches the original URL. Either use `location ^~ /live` or `^` at the beginning of the regex.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! location ^~ /live did the trick!